Python: Submitting and tracking many subprocesses leads to "stuck" subprocesses
I have an 3rd party cli executable I need to call from my python code. These are heavy calculations (cpu) and there are around 50-100 times I need to call it. The executable itself is to some degree multi-threaded but not all steps and I have a lot of cores available.
This means I want to have multiple subprocesses running at once but not all of them. So I need to submit some of them and then track once one of them completes, start a new one to optimize cpu usage.
I had a working version but it was very naive, but it worked. It just waited for the first submitted process to complete. But it is data-dependent, so at some point a very long running process was the "first" one submitted of the remaining ones and it will just block from any other process getting submitted until this one completes. There is also a long sequential/IO? phase and this long-running one can be at 1% cpu for hrs during which the cpu is then mostly idle.
So I needed to optimize my process submission code:
num_concurrent_processes = 6
for path in files:
    # Building cmd omitted
    rs_process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True,
                                                  bufsize=1, creationflags=0x00000008)
    rs_processes.append(rs_process) 

    if len(rs_processes) >= num_concurrent_processes:
        # wait until at least one process has completed before submitting the next one
        continue_polling = True
        while continue_polling:
            for idx, proc in enumerate(rs_processes):
                poll = proc.poll()
                if poll is not None:
                    # process complete
                    stdout_data, stderr_data = proc.communicate()
                    
                    # removed some logging in case of error
                    
                    #remove completed process from list
                    del rs_processes[idx]
                    # exit polling loop as a new subprocess can be submitted
                    continue_polling = False
                    break
            if continue_polling:
                # Put some breaks on the polling
                time.sleep(10)

I'm blocking submission of more subprocesses if the limit is reached. Then I poll until I find a process that finished (poll is not None according to python documentation). I get the output from the process via communicate and do some action on it (logging, not shown). Then I remove the process from the "tracking list" and exit from the polling loop.
But there is some kind of logic flaw in the code as when running it "stale" processes accumulate. They all sit at 0% but somehow the polling doesn't think they completed. And once there are num_concurrent_processes stale processes, progress stops entirely. What is going wrong here? Does using poll() mean I now need to manually terminate the process? With the old method all processes ran just fine and stopped on their own and I'm using the same data here with the new method.

Have you looked at Python's multiprocessing.Pool?

Can that deal with popen subprocesses?

The pool can run your python code with popen for one CLI executable. If there is a deadlock (executable expects some input, but Python waits for an output or something like that), only one instance will be affected.

Not directly. Using Pool or ThreadPool would only reduce the code you wrote for managing the processes but wouldn't solve the actual problem. Do these processes generate a lot of output? Maybe buffering the output of multiple processes needs too much memory. One way to check this is by redirecting the output to temporary files and to read the file when the process finished instead of using PIPE and communicate.

This is precisely what the various Pool classes are meant to be used for. Take a look in particular at ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor from the concurrent.futures module for ease of use

@MichaelButscher It works fine with the naive use-case and while logs can be "large" for manual looking at them they are still small (100mb) and there is plenty of RAM available.

If the process needs to write to stdout or stderr, it may block until you read from the corresponding pipes in Python. Thus, some processes may effectively be waiting for you to call communicate(), but you’re waiting until they exit before you call communicate().
You have a few options available to you:

Python asyncio provides functionality to use async programming to monitor many subprocesses in parallel; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html for more details and examples. You can use a semaphore to control the number of active subprocesses. This option provides the maximum flexibility as you can dynamically adjust how many subprocesses to launch based on e.g. CPU usage.
You can spawn a thread to handle each subprocess. Threads can block independently of each other, so each subprocess-handling thread can simply call .communicate.
You can use a multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool with a fixed number of worker threads. This is probably the most straightforward approach for your particular use case. Construct a ThreadPool with the number of workers set to the number of processes you want to run in parallel, then just call pool.map or a similar function to launch the jobs.

Here's a simple example of using ThreadPool to run a bunch of subprocesses:
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def run_subproc(cmd):
    # you can also use `subprocess.run` here directly
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)
    stdout, _ = proc.communicate()
    return stdout

def main():
    # whatever commands you want to run in your subprocess
    todo = [("echo", str(i)) for i in range(50)]

    # argument is the number of concurrent processes to run
    pool = ThreadPool(6)

    # if you want to get results sooner, but potentially out of order,
    # use pool.imap_unordered
    # chunksize=1 here tells the ThreadPool to issue jobs one at a time
    # to workers, instead of attempting to batch the jobs
    for result in pool.imap(run_subproc, todo, chunksize=1):
        print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Are you advocating multithreading (ThreadPool) for "heavy" CPU utilisation?

Since all the work is done in subprocesses, and the main process is just responsible for I/O with the subprocesses, ThreadPool will work fine and is less overhead than the process-based Pool.

How can I get the sdtout when using a ThreadPool?

I’ve added an example to my answer.

@nneonneo I have now tried concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor and the issue I face is that it's not respecting max_workers and submitting everything at once. Any input on that?

No idea, I don’t know what your code looks like. Maybe try the plain ThreadPool?

I changed to a normal ThreadPool. The downside here is that the user can't be informed as well what part of the calculation is getting submitted and is currently executing, I can only inform what has been completed. It's an acceptable compromise.
Additional as you can see from the original code I need to pass several arguments to the calculation function which is not possible by default for map/imap methods. Hence I use the workaround of a lambda function that takes 1 argument (a list) and then unpacks them (*args) and calls the actual calculation function.
to make this work I first need to iterate over the list of tasks and build this argument list.
finally the calculation function returns a tuple containing all the needed information.
This leads to below code structure:
subproc_arguments = []
for path in self.tasks:     
    # build args list for each task
    subproc_arguments.append(args)

for result in pool.imap_unordered(lambda args: submit_task(*args), subproc_arguments):
    id = result[0]
    stdout = result[1]
    return_code = result[2]
    # check results here
    
def submit_task(id, folder, log_verbosity):

    # build cmd
    rs_process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
                    text=True, bufsize=1, creationflags=0x00000008)
    stdout_data, stderr_data = rs_process.communicate()

    return id, stdout_data, rs_process.returncode

